# Fourier transform of $ \exp{\left(\text irx/\sqrt{1-\text ix}\right)}/(1-\text ix) $

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I want to calculate the following Fourier transform:

$$u(r,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text d\omega\ \frac{1}{1-\text i\omega}\, \exp\left\{\frac{\text ir \omega}{\sqrt{1-\text i \omega}} +\text i\omega t\right\} $$

However, when I try to put it in Mathematica, both

```
FourierTransform[Exp[I r x/Sqrt[1 - I x]]/(1 - I x), x, t, Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

and

```
Integrate[Exp[I r x/Sqrt[1 - I x] + I x t]/(1 - I x), {x, Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> r > 0 && t \[Element] Reals]
```

`FourierTransform` and `Integrate` commands, I get nothing the same command printed at the output after a while. Is there any other way to calculate this integral symbolically?

Comment: Please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/253368/edit) your question and add the code you've tried. The code will help people understand your problem.

Comment: panoik, please add mathematica code to your post

Comment: At first you wrote `x` and next `omega`.What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Just updated it!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It is the exact same integral with just a different variable name. $\omega$ doesn't symbolize anything different than $x$.

Comment: For `r>0` and `t>=0`  Real part of Fourier Transform is: `0`. For `r>0` and `t<0`, I have found  solution by complex  infinty series .I doubt there's a closed form for the Fourier Transform.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk This seems very interesting, how do you use complex infinity series?

Comment: Try: `Sum[FourierTransform[((I r x)/Sqrt[1 - I x])^j/j!/(1 - I x) // 
   PowerExpand, x, t, Assumptions -> {r > 0, Re[t] < 0, j >= 0}], {j, 
  0, Infinity}]`